# JQuery use jquery.foggy to blur only a div's background

Tags: jquery, html, background, blur

I have a div, need to blur only it's background (image) using the following plugin-
http://nbartlomiej.github.io/foggy/

Any workarounds for this?

JQuery:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $('#desc').foggy();
 });
```

"#desc" is my div.

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward solution seems be to put another div over one with the image. Another might be to add a class to the image and blur that.

```
 #desc is the div,
 .desc-img is the class inside that div
```

The jQuery then becomes

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.desc-img').foggy();
});
```

Comment: Yeah but I can't just make the img absolute because there are more elements below the div.